# Pandas Python: calculating financial week number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have five years of data related to finance. The financial year starts on 1st July and ends on 30th June. I want to calculate the financial week of each financial year. I want to apply some operation on the date column of the data frame so that when I write something like `df['date].dt.week`, it should return the financial week number instead of returning the calendar week number. So I used the following code to perform the desired output:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.Period,freq='W')
df['date'].dt.week
```

But it did not produce the desired result. Could anyone guide me to where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `pandas`. However, you can use the vectorized function that I have created below called `business_week` (while I was at it, I also created one for `business day`). These functions account for leap year. This function starts counting as of the first day of the month/day you pass rather than a specific day of the week. Please note that there are 52 full weeks in a year and 1 or 2 extra days depending on leap year, so June 30th will show up as week `53` and June 29th will as well for leap year. You can simply replace 53 with 52 if you want it to be 52. You have to pass the following parameters:

1. The column you want to derive business week in datetime format
2. The start month
3. The start day

For example: `df['week'] = business_week(df['date'], 7, 1)` and a minimum reproducible example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': 
{0: pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
1: pd.Timestamp('2019-06-28 00:00:00'),
2: pd.Timestamp('2019-06-29 00:00:00'),
3: pd.Timestamp('2019-06-30 00:00:00'),
4: pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00'),
5: pd.Timestamp('2019-07-07 00:00:00'),
6: pd.Timestamp('2019-07-08 00:00:00'),
7: pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
8: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00'),
9: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'),
10: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'),
11: pd.Timestamp('2020-07-01 00:00:00'),
12: pd.Timestamp('2020-07-07 00:00:00'),
13: pd.Timestamp('2020-07-08 00:00:00')}})

def business_week(d, start_month, start_day):
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    y_int = d.dt.year
    y_str = y_int.astype(str)
    start_md = (datetime(2020, start_month, start_day) - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m-%d')
    start_ymd = pd.to_datetime(y_str + '-' + start_md)
    s = d.dt.dayofyear - start_ymd.dt.dayofyear
    m1 = s.mask(s < 1, 365 - abs(s))
    m2 = m1.mask((y_int % 4 == 0) & (d > start_ymd), m1 - 1)
    return np.where(y_int % 4 != 0, (m2 + 6) / 7, (m2 + 7) / 7).astype(int)


df['week'] = business_week(df['date'], 7, 1)
df
Out[1]: 
         date  week
0  2019-01-01    27
1  2019-06-28    52
2  2019-06-29    52
3  2019-06-30    53
4  2019-07-01     1
5  2019-07-07     1
6  2019-07-08     2
7  2020-01-01    27
8  2020-06-28    52
9  2020-06-29    53
10 2020-06-30    53
11 2020-07-01     1
12 2020-07-07     1
13 2020-07-08     2
```

---

Also, if you wanted it you could use a similar method to return `business_day`:

```
def business_day(d, start_month, start_day):
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    y_int = d.dt.year
    y_str = y_int.astype(str)
    start_md = (datetime(2020, start_month, start_day) - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m-%d')
    start_ymd = pd.to_datetime(y_str + '-' + start_md)
    s = d.dt.dayofyear - start_ymd.dt.dayofyear
    m1 = s.mask(s < 1, 365 - abs(s))
    m2 = m1.mask((y_int % 4 == 0) & (d <= start_ymd), m1 + 1)
    return m2


df['day'] = business_day(df['date'], 7, 1)
df
Out[1]: 
         date  day
0  2019-01-01  185
1  2019-06-28  363
2  2019-06-29  364
3  2019-06-30  365
4  2019-07-01    1
5  2019-07-07    7
6  2019-07-08    8
7  2020-01-01  185
8  2020-06-28  364
9  2020-06-29  365
10 2020-06-30  366
11 2020-07-01    1
12 2020-07-07    7
13 2020-07-08    8
```

Answer (score 0):

`Series.dt.week` id deprecated. I haven't come across a financial year week. Maybe set start of week number to  start from a certain date.

Normal week of the year number I would try  the following after coercing date to date-time

```
df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x,freq='D').week)
```

or

```
df['date'].dt.strftime("%W").astype(int)
```

Comment: I did not know `dt.week` was deprecated. It appears that `dt.weekofyear` is also deprecated: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.week.html . It sounds like the best way now is `dt.isocalendar().week`

Comment: @David Erickson, will edit my answer to expunge it. nice one mate!